# `e2fsck -n` + how to know if need to run e2fsck in order to fix corrupted blocks?

Tags: linux, filesystems, filesystem-corruption, fsck, block-device

We want to check the filesystem on the disks as `/deb/sdc`  ... `/dev/sdg` on each Red Hat Linux machine.

The target is to find what are the disks that require `e2fsck` ( as `e2fsck -y /dev/sdb` etc.)

According to man page

> `-n`
>   Open  the filesystem read-only, and assume an answer of 'no' to all questions.  Allows `e2fsck` to be used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the same time as the `-p` or `-y` options.

When we run the command (example)

```
 e2fsck -n /dev/sdXX
```

we get

> ```
> e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
> Warning!  /dev/sdc is mounted.
> Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
> /dev/sdc: clean, 94/1310720 files, 156685/5242880 blocks
> ```

So what do we need to capture from `e2fsck -n` output, that requires us to run `e2fsck` (without `-n`)?

**e2fsck process**

```
init 1
umount /dev/sdXX
e2fsck -y /dev/sdXX  # (or e2fsck -C /dev/sdXX for full details) 
init 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `e2fsck` so I assume we're talking about `ext?` filesystem. The command

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdXX
```

will tell you the apparent state of the filesystem (which can be mounted, it's safe). You will get (among other things) either

> ```
> Filesystem state:   clean
> ```

or something else than `clean`. Because `grep` returns false if the match is not found, your basic try can be like this:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdXX | grep "^Filesystem state:[ ]*clean$" || { commands; to; fix; the; filesystem; }
```

---

The above will work only if the filesystem detected its unclean state beforehand. Sometimes you want to check for problems anyway (that's why the desired behavior is to `fsck` every Nth mount or when such-and-such number of days have passed). If I get you right you're trying to get to know if you should `e2fsck -y /dev/sdXX`, by analyzing the output of `e2fsck -n /dev/sdXX`.

I say don't analyze the output. Check the exit status. See [`man 8 e2fsck`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck) to learn:

> The exit code returned by `e2fsck` is the sum of the following conditions:
>   `0` - No errors
>   `1` - File system errors corrected
>   `2` - File system errors corrected, system should
>   be rebooted
>   `4` - File system errors left uncorrected
>   `8` - Operational error
>   `16` - Usage or syntax error
>   `32` - `e2fsck` canceled by user request
>   `128` - Shared library error

Note `e2fsck -n /dev/sdXX` will do nothing useful (and it will return "no errors") if the filesystem *seems* clear; so this is another way to detect the current *apparent* state, like we did with `tune2fs`. To check anyway you need `-f` option. Then **you want to know if the exit status includes `4`**. In `bash` this can be done with:

```
e2fsck -nf /dev/sdXX  # this is safe even if the filesystem is mounted
status=$?
[ $(( $status & 4 )) -eq 4 ] && { commands; to; fix; the; filesystem; }
```

Quick explanation:

- `$?` is the exit status of the last command (`e2fsck` in this case). I save it to a separate variable so I can do multiple tests with it. It's not necessary in this simple example where there is one test only, but a good practice in general. The underlying reason is: after these lines `$status` still contains exit status of `e2fsck` and can be reused, while (the new) `$?` has nothing to do with `e2fsck`.
- `$(( ... ))` does shell arithmetic
- where `&` is bitwise AND,
- then `[ ... -eq 4 ]` is in fact the `test` command to check if the result is `4`.
- If the test succeeds then the `{ ... }` block will be executed.

---

There may be errors not within the filesystem itself but on deeper level, on the device. I think this is out of scope of this question but just to point you in the right direction in case you need it, these are useful commands (notice `sdX`, not `sdXX`):

- `smartctl -t long /dev/sdX`
- `badblocks -n -b 512 /dev/sdX`

Read their man pages before you use them.

Comment: thank you so much for the long and excellent answer , just one note why not do the --> [[ $? -eq 4 ]] && e2fsck -y /dev/sdXX , its more simple

Comment: second -  is it safe to run the e2fsck -nf  /dev/sdXX while device is mounted ?

Comment: @KingDavid `[ $? -eq 4 ]` misses e.g. `12` which is `4+8`. You probably won't get this value. It's up to you what logic you will use, whether you'll check for `128` or not, etc. If you want to match exactly `4` then `[ $? -eq 4 ]` should do fine. `e2fsck -nf /dev/sdXX` is safe because `-n` makes it read-only, therefore the command cannot break anything. A separate question is: can the mounted state alter the conclusion? This I don't know. I assume you need to probe health of a filesystem without disrupting normal operations. Obviously you should `umount` before `e2fsck -y`.

Comment: @KingDavid I have deliberately spoiled my (test) filesystem with some `dd` commands and got exit code `12` from `e2fsck -nf`. I think you shouldn't check for sole `4`; use my bitwise-aware code better.

Answer (score 0):

First check if it is Journaling file system.

"A journaling file system is a file system that keeps track of changes not yet committed to the file system's main part by recording the intentions of such changes in a data structure known as a "journal", which is usually a circular log. In the event of a system crash or power failure, such file systems can be brought back online more quickly with a lower likelihood of becoming corrupted."

Then you can try Gparted to check for consistency and see what the tool can do for you.